# How apply a customized css to an Rmarkdown document with selected a theme?

Tags: r, r-markdown

For instance, I am using the `flatly` theme from Rmarkdown to generate a HTML file.

I want to apply some customize css to this theme, but nothing has change. It seems that my css file does not work on the predefined Markdown theme.

Below is the YAML file of my Rmarkdown document.

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: true
    css: style.css
---
```

Here is my style.css file

```
/* Whole document: */
body{
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
}

/* Quoted text  */
blockquote{
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: white;
  border-left: 0.2em solid #76D7C4;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Code text  */

code {
  background: #ffcccc.
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to open the file in a browser like Chrome and use developers tools to check that (i) your CSS is included in your code and (ii) if yes, what precisely happens to the properties, like why are they overwritten.

Comment: It's actually working. You just have two problems. **(i)** `background:` property of `code` is being overwritten by rmarkdown defaults. So to solve it use `!important` like `background: #ffcccc !important;` and **(ii)** you have used full-stop in `background: #ffcccc.` at the end where you need to use semi-colon `;`